# Incorrect result of Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

Let us consider in 12.3.1 on Windows 10

```
k = Integrate[a^(I*x)*Log[x]/x, {x, b, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a > 1 && b > 0]
```

> `Gamma[0, -I b Log[a]] Log[b] -  1/2 \[Pi] (-2 I EulerGamma + \[Pi] - 2 I Log[Log[a]]) +  MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {}}, -I b Log[a]]`

This result is not correct in view of

```
N[k /. {b -> 1, a -> Exp[1]}, 20]
```

> `-5.3018807841496144201 + 1.8884990455871598385 I`

which is not in accordance with

```
NIntegrate[Exp[1]^(I*x)*Log[x]/x, {x, 1, Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"ExtrapolatingOscillatory", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
```

> `-0.367079 + 0.0751224 I`

and

```
Integrate[Exp[1]^(I*x)*Log[x]/x, {x, 1, Infinity}]
```

> `1/24 (12 EulerGamma^2 - 12 I EulerGamma \[Pi] - \[Pi]^2 +  24 I HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2}, {3/2, 3/2, 3/2}, -(1/4)] -  3 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1}, {3/2, 2, 2, 2}, -(1/4)])`

```
N[%]
```

> `-0.367079+0.0751226 I`

Can a true formula for `k` be derived in Mathematica?

Comment: This `Integrate[Exp[I*A* x]*Log[x]/x, {x, b, Infinity}, Assumptions -> A > 0 && b > 0]` works for me and gives `EulerGamma^2/2 - (I EulerGamma \[Pi])/2 - \[Pi]^2/24 + I A b HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, I A b] + 
 EulerGamma Log[A] - 1/2 I \[Pi] Log[A] + Log[A]^2/2 + 
 EulerGamma Log[b] + Gamma[0, -I A b] Log[b] - Log[b]^2/2 + 
 Log[b] Log[-I A b]`.

Comment: Nice to see it.  Can you present this comment as an answer?

Comment: I am hesitant a bit because I did not do much and because it is a complete mystery to me as to why MA treats these two different but equivalent forms so differently.

Comment: `Integrate[E^(I*x)*Log[x]/x, {x, 1, Infinity}] // N[#, 20] &` is consistent with the `NIntegrate` results.